# Unable to send email in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendmail

I'm using `Codeigniter` to send email from my PHP script.

**My code to send mail is:**

```
// Library must be loaded first 
            $this->load->library('email');


            $config = array(
                        'protocol'      =>      'smtp',
                        'smtp_host'     =>      'smtp.gmail.com',
                        'smtp_port'     =>      587,
                        'smtp_user'     =>      'khaksar445@gmail.com',
                        'smtp_pass'     =>      'mypass'
                    );


            $this->email->initialize($config);

            $this->email->from($email, 'User');
            $this->email->to('khaksar445@gmail.com');
            $this->email->subject($sub);
            $this->email->message($body);


            if($this->email->send())
            {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success>Email sent successfully</div>"';
            }
            else
            {
                echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            }
```

**The error i'm getting is:**

> Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.

Is there any way to solve this problem.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need configure your web server to sending emails.

Comment: But how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Set you `config` Like this..

```
$config = Array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
  'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // change it to yours
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sendmail`

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from('khaksar445@gmail.com', 'SIte Name ');
$this->email->to('to@address.lk');
```

> **FYI :** If you use gmail, its fine. But you cant track the actual error always. Use server mail host. If something out you know its an coding issue.

Comment: Exit status code: 1
Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.
Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: Still unable to send mail